# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir el máximo de una sucesión de números dada por el usuario?

Tags: javascript, array

Quiero hacer un programa que distinga el número más grande de una sucesión, logré hacer que el código funcionara así:

```
let answerX = parseInt(prompt('¿Cuánto vale x?'));
let answerY = parseInt(prompt('¿Cuánto vale y?'));
let answerZ = parseInt(prompt('¿Cuánto vale z?'));

let  num    = [answerX, answerY, answerZ];
let  max    = 0;
let  length = num.length;

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  if (num[i] > max) {
    max = num[i];
  }
}

console.log(num[0]);
console.log(num[1]);
console.log(num[2]);
console.log('El máximo es ' + max);
```

Pero quise que usuario pudiese poner tantos números como quisiese, así que he tratado de hacer esto:

```
let answer;
let num = [];
let max = 0;
let stop = 1;
let length = num.length;
let cycle = true;

while (cycle == true) {

  answer = parseInt(prompt('Inserte los números... bip bop  (n para finalizar)'));
  num.push(answer);
  console.log(num);

  if (answer == stop) {
    cycle = false;
    let index = num.indexOf(length);
    num.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(num);
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {

  if (num[i] > max) {
    max = num[i];
  }
}

console.log('El máximo es ' + max);
```

Solo que he tenido muchos problemas evidentemente, primero traté de volver los datos ingresados por el usuario un valor número mediante el parseInt dentro del for:

```
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  if (parseInt(num[i]) > max) {
    max = parseInt(num[i]);
  }
}
```

Pero al ejecutar la variante max sigue en 0 hasta el final del flujo y al convertir el prompt en parseInt, puedo hacer que todo el array sean valores numéricos sin embargo igualmente el valor max sigue en 0 hasta el final, además de que la 'n' ya no se puede usar para terminar el ciclo ¿Alguien me puede echar la mano con este embrollo? Soy nuevo en el mundillo.
Gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `num.splice` en lugar de `num.push` para agregar tus elementos al array?

Answer (score 1):

En este caso, ya que estas usando un ciclo while, puedes comparar con el numero mayor cada vez que el usuario ingresa un numero nuevo.  Algo asi:

```js
let answer;
let max = 0;
let stop = 1;
let cycle = true;

while (cycle == true) {

  answer = parseInt(prompt('Inserte los números... bip bop  (n para finalizar)'));
  if (answer > max) {
    max = answer;
  }
  
  if (answer == stop) {
    cycle = false;
    
  }
}

console.log('El máximo es ' + max);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo quería notar que JavaScript coerciona a `true` o `false` los números cuando se los somete a una evaluación lógica, el 0 es "interpretado" como `false`, los demás como `true`, lo que hace posible evaluar directamente el resultado del `prompt` siempre que le antepongamos `+` para coercionar la respuesta del prompt (string) como numérico:

```js
let max = 0;
let ans = 1;

while (ans) {

  ans = +prompt('Inserte los números');

  max = ans > max ? ans : max;

}

console.log('El máximo es ' + max);
```

Si introducimos letras, el `+"string"` se coerciona como `NaN` que en una evaluación lógica se coerciona como `false`.

Comment: perdona que significa esto   max = ans > max ? ans : max;   lo unico que vi parecido era el operador termario pero no entiendo eso

Comment: Claro, es un oeprador ternario. si  la respuesta (ans) es mayor al máximo ( ans > max) el máximo pasa a ser la respuesta (ans > max ? ans ) sino (;) queda el máximo anterior (max).

Comment: es una forma muy buena y resumida de hacerlo, gracias.